# "Unfortunately, app has stopped" error message when I try the app in the emulator

Tags: java, android

I made an android app through android studio and it successfully compiled but when I try it on the emulator I get this error message:
"Unfortunately, app has stopped"
Can anyone please help me?

LogCat:

```
04-25 15:19:26.613 5309-5309/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-25 15:19:27.446 5309-5309/com.coolclassicgamehandwarriorsepicbattleshoeshoot2playerbeatchildhoodplayfamilyfriendsagainstcomputerrpsboardrockpaperscissorss D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-25 15:19:27.447 5309-5309/com.coolclassicgamehandwarriorsepicbattleshoeshoot2playerbeatchildhoodplayfamilyfriendsagainstcomputerrpsboardrockpaperscissorss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.coolclassicgamehandwarriorsepicbattleshoeshoot2playerbeatchildhoodplayfamilyfriendsagainstcomputerrpsboardrockpaperscissorss, PID: 5309
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:  to add a valid  *
    * App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
    * follow instructions here: .                           *
    ******************************************************************************


        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4633)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4573)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:  to add a valid  *
    * App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
    * follow instructions here: .                           *
    ******************************************************************************


        at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabg.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5038)
            ... 11 more
04-25 15:19:30.305 5309-5309/com.coolclassicgamehandwarriorsepicbattleshoeshoot2playerbeatchildhoodplayfamilyfriendsagainstcomputerrpsboardrockpaperscissorss I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5309 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
 and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Change your theme name in AndroidMenifest.xml file

android->manifest-> then change to android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: Or use this one 
android->manifest-> then change to android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: This has nothing to do with themes

Comment: i have changed my theme name and my app run correctly  and if it does not work on your current emulator so you need to change your emulator or run application on mobile device thank you

Comment: already have the same theme name as yours